# Xamarin Forms: Remove or Hide the LinearAxis from the Piechart

Tags: c#, charts, oxyplot

How to remove oxyplot linear Axis lines(black border line as shown in image).

I tried to hide the visibility of axis lines using below code,but the lines are still visible

Code:

```
modelP2.Series.Add(seriesP2);
        modelP2.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis() { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, IsAxisVisible = false, AxislineStyle = LineStyle.None, MinorTicklineColor=OxyColors.Transparent, ExtraGridlineColor =OxyColors.Transparent, MajorGridlineColor=OxyColors.Transparent, MinorGridlineColor =OxyColors.Transparent,TicklineColor=OxyColors.Transparent, AxislineColor =OxyColors.Transparent, TickStyle = TickStyle.None,MinorTickSize = 0, MajorTickSize=0 });
        modelP2.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis() { Position = AxisPosition.Left, IsAxisVisible = false, AxislineStyle = LineStyle.None, MinorTicklineColor = OxyColors.Transparent, ExtraGridlineColor = OxyColors.Transparent , MajorGridlineColor = OxyColors.Transparent, MinorGridlineColor = OxyColors.Transparent, TicklineColor = OxyColors.Transparent, AxislineColor = OxyColors.Transparent, TickStyle = TickStyle.None });
       // modelP2.DefaultXAxis.AxislineColor = OxyColors.White;
        var ta = new TextAnnotation();
        ta.Text = "Label Text";
        ta.TextColor = OxyColors.Black;
        ta.Stroke = OxyColors.Transparent;
        ta.StrokeThickness = 5;
        ta.FontSize = 36;
        ta.TextPosition = new DataPoint(50, 50);
        modelP2.Annotations.Add(ta);
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. IMHO, that isn't the Axis which results in Black Lines, but rather Plot Area Border. You should be able to remove it changing color to transparent

```
modelP2.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;
```